# Pivot table with Vlookup or sumif

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I got 2 table, one is a pivot table that has usernames and hours of work in it.
second table has username and the payment per hour

I want to have an answer in one column besides the 1st table with the hours * payment for worker.
For example:

```
nik  12  Total 240$              nik 20$(in a different sheet""master)
john 15  Total 315$              john 21$(in a different sheet"master")
```

i did a vlookup that works but ONLY if both of the username columns are the same order.

```
=(VLOOKUP(A2:A25,master!A2:B24,2,FALSE))*(VLOOKUP(master!A2:A24,A2:B25,2,FALSE))
```

Is it possible to make the 1st column to search from the second one even if its out of the order?

-Nik

Comment: If anyone is interested I found the answer:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,master!A:B,2,FALSE)*B3,"")
(added an error manage as well)

Comment: Post this as new answer and mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I found the answer: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,master!A:B,2,FALSE)*B3,"") (added an error manage as well